# Прогрузка всех страниц webView в viewPager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

Есть несколько вкладок, которые перелистывают `viewPager`. В каждом окне есть `webView`, отвечающий за определенную страницу. Но когда перелистываешь `viewPager` на несколько позиций вперед, `WebView` начинает грузить страницу. Можно ли при запуске этого окна с вкладками прогружать одновременно все страницы, а потом просто переключаться между ними?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете увеличить `offscreenPageLimit` у `ViewPager`:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pageCount);
```

Значение по умолчанию 1. То есть грузятся по одной страницы слева и справа от текущей. Но я бы не советовал прогружать сразу все страницы, потому что начнут инициализироваться все `WebView`, что может привести к заметным подтормаживаниям интерфейса, так как это очень тяжелый компонент в андроиде. Лучше поэксперементировать и выбрать какое-то оптимальное число страниц.